# Convert data on reading csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a .csv file into a pandas dataframe.  The .csv file contains several columns.  Column 'A' contains a string '20-989-98766'.  Is it possible to only read the last 5 characters '98766' from the string when loading the file?

```
df = pd.read_csv("test_data2.csv", column={'A':read the last 5 characters})
```

output:

```
A
98766
95476
.....
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a `func` and pass this as an arg to `converters` param for [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv):

```
In [57]:
import io
import pandas as pd
def func(x):
    return x[-5:]
t="""column
'20-989-98766"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), converters={'column': func})
df

​
Out[57]:
  column
0  98766
```

So here I define a `func` and pass this to `converters` in the form of a dict with your column name as the key, this will call the `func` on every row in your csv

so in your case the following should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("test_data2.csv", converters={'A':func})
```

Comment: If your file doesn't have any headers, then you could set the `Header` to `None` which would create the 0th column for a single column, and then you could just do the following similar to what @EdChum has described:


`df = pd.read_csv("test_data2.csv", header=None, converters={0:func})`