# Trailing space causing column names to not match in read_csv with usecols

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've got a few thousand similarly formatted csv files, and I'm reading in two columns from each of them.  They may be in different orders, and the main issue seems to be that there is a trailing space at the end of every line, including the header.  So say I have a few headers that look like this:

```
'apple','banana','orange '
'banana','kiwi','apple '
'grape','apple','banana '
```

and I am doing this in a for loop to save all data in a dict:

```
results[fruitfilepath] = pd.read_csv(fruitfilepath,usecols=['apple', 'banana']
```

which works up until it hits a file with 'apple' or 'banana' as the last column, and thus has a space after it.

In theory I can think of three ways to deal with this, but I'm struggling with implementing them.

1st, is there a way to include a wildcard in usecols?  Something like the following (which doesn't work).

```
results[fruitfilepath] = pd.read_csv(fruitfilepath,usecols=['apple*', 'banana*']
```

2nd, use multiple column names, but somehow trigger read_csv to skip over columns that don't existing in the file.

```
results[fruitfilepath] = pd.read_csv(fruitfilepath,usecols=['apple', 'banana','apple ', 'banana ']
```

3rd, preprocess all the files by removing all trailing spaces.  This is fairly simple, but just seems excessive, and I assume there is a better way.

4th, something else I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like you might be able to use 'converters' to rename the columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350601/convert-data-on-reading-csv-in-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do a combination of your 2nd and 3rd options, manually set the column names by reading the first row and working out what the headers should be called on the fly.

Read the first line to get a list of column names currently

```
headers_df = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv", nrows=1, header = None)
```

Convert the headers to a list

```
headers = headers_df.values.tolist()[0]
```

Fix the column names to remove the spaces

```
fixed_headers = [x.strip(' ') for x in headers]
```

manually replace the file headers with the fixed ones, selecting the two that you need

```
d = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=0, names=fixed_headers, usecols=['apple','banana'])
```

Comment: Nice and simple, thanks!  Just in case someone else comes along to reference, you have a small typo with the capital H in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Insert into `df.columns` a list of the original `n-1` columns + the last column minus its last character

```
df.columns = df.columns[:-1].to_list() + [df.columns[-1][:-1]]
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [2, 3], 'cd': [3, 4]})
df.columns = df.columns[:-1].to_list() + [df.columns[-1][:-1]]
df.columns
```

output:
`Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')`

That's my approach, (I think) you can do whatever string manipulation you want on `df.columns[-1]`.

Comment: But how do you get df.columns in the first place?

Comment: @JeffUK Every dataframe have columns. If I understand OP's code correctly, he loads dataframes into a dictionary, so in his code that would be `results[fruitfilepath].columns`.

Comment: @JeffUK If my previous comment is obvious and that was not what you meant me to answer, maybe I'm not really seeing the problem. From my understanding, OP can load his csv file into a dataframe, and the problem is when one of the columns (the last one), is named `banana ` with a trailing space. When he tries to access the column using `df['banana']` he gets a key error since the right column name is `banana ` (trailing space here too).