# Python/Pandas:How to process a column of data like a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a csv lie this

```
cel_id|PDCP.RxBytesUl
1001-1234-1|5QI1:0.0001;5QI2:0.0002;5QI3:0.0003;5QI4:0.0004;5QI5:0.0005;5QI6:0.0006;5QI7:0.0007;5QI8:0.0008;5QI9:0.0009
1001-1234-2|5QI1:0.0001;5QI2:0.0003;5QI3:0.0005;5QI4:0.0007;5QI5:0.0009;5QI6:0.0010;5QI7:0.0000;5QI8:0.0000;5QI9:0.0128
1001-1234-4|5QI1:0.0001;5QI2:0.0003;5QI3:0.0005;5QI4:0.0007;5QI5:0.0009;5QI6:0.0010;5QI7:0.0010;5QI8:0.0030;5QI9:0.0020
```

i would like to sum the values from column "PDCP.RxBytesUl",

`PDCP.RxBytesUl = 5QI1+5QI2+5QI3+5QI4+5QI5+5QI6+5QI7+5QI8+5QI9`

finally,the result is like this

```
 cel_id      PDCP.RxBytesUl
1001-1234-1  0.0045
1001-1234-2  0.0163
1001-1234-4  0.0095
```

At first I wanted to convert this column into a dict(), but I found the format was not right, i have no idea, please help me, thank you

Comment: define a function that parse the string in the column and return the sum. pass that function as part of `converters` argument in `pd.read_csv()`. don't forget to set `sep='|'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert data on reading csv in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350601/convert-data-on-reading-csv-in-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regex based solution:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',delimiter='|')

df['sum'] = df['PDCP.RxBytesUl'].str.extractall(':(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)').astype('float').unstack().sum(axis=1)
df.drop('PDCP.RxBytesUl', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

---

**df:**

```
    cel_id      sum
0   1001-1234-1 0.0045
1   1001-1234-2 0.0163
2   1001-1234-4 0.0095
```

---

Better code Suggested by Shubham :)

```
df['sum'] = df['PDCP.RxBytesUl'].str.extractall(':([^;]+)').astype('float').sum(level=0)
df.drop('PDCP.RxBytesUl', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You can also use `sum(level=0)` in place of `unsatck and sum`  and may be regex pattern `':([^;]+)'` would suffice:)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma that regex line :O. Thanks. I just started with regex :( still a noob.

Answer (score 1):

You could read your csv file and convert the content of the column of interest:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(
    'input.csv', 
    delimiter='|', 
    converters={'PDCP.RxBytesUl': lambda x: sum(float(y.split(':')[1]) for y in x.split(';'))}
)
```

The previous code produces:

```sh
        cel_id  PDCP.RxBytesUl
0  1001-1234-1          0.0045
1  1001-1234-2          0.0163
2  1001-1234-4          0.0095
```